# Azure storage account displays: No blobs found

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I have created a storage account in azure portal and a stream-analytics job that receives data from Iot-Hub and sends it's output to a blob in the storage account.
When I tested the input and output connections in the stream-analytics job account, it verified me that the connections are o.k.

But After sending telematric data to Iot-Hub, I see that the data was indeed received in the storage account, but when entering the blob container and clicking the blob, it displays: **No blobs found.**

I would be glad to hear any suggestions to what might be the problem,
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But After sending telematric data to Iot-Hub, I see that the data was indeed received in the storage account, but when entering the blob container and clicking the blob, it displays: No blobs found.

According to your description, I assumed that your job has no output data. I recommend that you could follow the steps below to check with this issue:

- Click "MONITORING > Metrics" under your Stream Analytics job;
- Check the metrics for Input Events, Runtime Errors, Data Conversion Errors.

  - If **Input Events** > 0, the ASA job is able to read data. If not, then you need to check with your input.
  - If **Runtime Errors** > 0, means that the ASA Job is able to receive the data but is getting errors while processing the query. Go to the Operation Logsand filter on "Failed" status to find all these errors.
  - If **InputEvents** > 0 and **OutputEvents** = 0, means one of the following:

    - Query processing resulted in zero output events.
    - Events or its fields may be malformed, so resulted in zero output after query processing.
    - Unable to push data to the output sink for connectivity/authentication reasons.
    - In all of these error cases, operations log messages explain additional details (including what is happening), except for the cases the query logic filtered out all events. If the processing of multiple events generates errors, Stream Analytics logs the first 3 error messages of the same type within 10 minutes to Operations logs and then suppress additional identical errors with a message that reads "Errors are happening too rapidly, these are being suppressed".

Additionally, if you are still not able to figure out the cause, you could go to operations log, select one of the latest entries and click Details button then provide all the details, then we could help you to troubleshoot this issue.